# Runtime decision to append Where/And

Tags: sql-server, dynamicquery

If I have a query stored in a table like this :

```
1. 'SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable'
2. 'SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable Where car_id = 1'
```

Can someone suggest me, how can I append another filter to both queries?

Ex : I need it like this:

```
1. 'SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable **Where foo_id = 10**' (with where)
2. 'SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable Where car_id = 1 **and foo_id = 10**' (with and as where already exist).
```

Comment: Append `WHERE 1 = 1` as default condition to the query. That way, you will have `AND ` condition to add in all cases.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: i agree. But these queries are already exist in db, now if i want to append 1=1, again same question arises.

Comment: With help of `PATINDEX` function to check if the string contains ` WHERE `, you may add `WHERE` if it does not exist, `AND` otherwise.

Comment: @shahkalpesh : We have couple of scenarios where you see WHERE clause in INNER queries as well. For ex :
Select * from table1
Join (Select Id, value From Table2 where statsusId = 2)
In such cases it is failing.

Comment: See my previous comment on using `PATINDEX`.